# What happened to the rest of the Tie-Fighters?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

During the battle on Crait,

> The Millennium Falcon shows up and starts attacking Tie-Fighters. Kylo Ren then orders all of the other Tie-Fighters to destroy the Falcon, and they pursue it across the cliffs.

They managed to

> lead some to their destruction and shoot down some others, but considering that they were being pursued by an entire squadron (a point is made that every Tie-Fighter attacking the base goes after the Falcon), it didn't seem to show enough being destroyed on-screen to suggest that they had all been wiped out.

Is there any suggestion that there were more Tie-Fighters that were still looking for their target after it had evaded them, or had they actually all been destroyed?

Comment: The implication was that they were all destroyed. We will probably find out more when the novelization comes out.

Comment: They weren't just destroyed, they were destroyed by following the Millennium Falcon through a maze at high speeds. You'd think they'd teach Tie fighters about that by now

Comment: @Machavity to paraphrase Finn "Man, they *hate* that ship"

Comment: Rey was such a natural with the belly gun I figured they were mostly destroyed by the time Chewie flew thru the cavern.

Comment: @scott you mean the force ensured each shot was true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Some were destroyed before entering the caves and the remainder during the cave-chase sequence.**

---

When the Falcon leaves the battlefield it's noted that **every single TIE-fighter** went with them.

> **Poe:** *She drew 'em off. All of them!!*

A few seconds later we see at least 9 (of the remaining 14(ish) TIE-fighters that were seen a few minutes ago) chasing the Falcon. Rey splashes at least one with the cannon and there's the sound of a second explosion. They then enter the cave. One TIE hits an outcropping, another hits a stalagmite, two more hit the cave walls as they narrow and the final two that were chasing them *aren't* seen emerging from the cave wall that the Falcon broke through.

The cannon appears to be broken so at this point (sparking and non-functional) so it's **a reasonable guess that all of the fighters were destroyed by this point**. This also explains the Falcon's absence from the next few minutes of the film as Chewie and Rey were presumably struggling to get the gun working again.

---

The film's [official junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_A_Junior_Novel) confirms the destruction of the remaining enemy ships.

> *The Falcon made an abrupt drop into a crevice, a move most of the TIEs
>   failed in spectacular fashion. Some smashed into the surface, others
>   into the sides of the crevice, and **all went up in flames.***